Physics of quantum beats in atomic vapor
Assume a low-pressure, low temperature-gas of atom subject to "vacuum fluctuations" where each atom is in the same superposition of two hyperfine states, both with an allowed transition to the same ground state [J. Carlsson, Z. Phys. D - Atoms, Molecules and Clusters 9, t47-151 (1988)]. Further assume that the fluorescent radiation is to be measured with a old-fashioned high resolution spectrograph and photographic plate having sufficient resolution to produce two narrow lines with plenty of empty space between them when each hyperfine state is excited separately. Finally assume that the experiment is set up so that only one photon is present between the vapor and the photographic plate during as many decay measurements as needed to produce a well defined pattern.
Will the pattern recorded on the plate be the two hyperfine lines or will it be a quantum-beat interference pattern spread across plate with peaks at the location of the individual hyperfine lines? If the latter, why weren't quantum beats discovered prior to 1926?  I'm guessing that doppler and collision broading masked the effect in emission spectroscopy such as in Zeeman's first publication and the pertinent absorption spectroscopy was done with the spectrograph on the input side of the sample rather than on the output side. But I am not comforatble with a guess and hope that someone can direct me to a definitive publications, which I have not been able to identify.
This is not a homwork or test question. I know that quantum beats have been attributed to single photons emitted by atoms in a superposition of hyperfine states as well as a collective phenomena involving multiple photons emitted by atoms in an eigenstate as well a multiple photons generated by splitting a laser beam into two laser beams, phase shifting one, and beating them against each other.  But it seems to me that single-photon detection at different spacial locations is the only way to differentiate the single-photon phenamena from the latter.
